# Maven - how to create ejb client when packing war

Tags: maven-3

I've an eclipse base ejb project that I have just converted into a maven module.  It is structured in web app layout (as preferred by Tomee).  So, in pom.xml, the  packaging type is set to war, which maven correctly generated the war file.  But I'm not very successful in getting maven to also create a ejb-client jar when packaging the war.  I added this to the pom.xml but it does not seems to be doing anything:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>BossClient</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                        <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                        <clientIncludes>
                            <clientInclude>/com/**</clientInclude>
                        </clientIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Any idea how I can get maven to generate the ejb-client when packaging the war?

Answer (score 3):

The configuration of [maven-ejb-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/) can be simplified like this:

```xml
<project>
   <groupId>..</groupId>
   <artifactId>..</artifactId>

   <packaging>ejb</packagin>

   <build>
     <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
         <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
         <configuration>
           <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
           <generateClient>true</generateClient>
           <clientIncludes>
             <clientInclude>/com/**</clientInclude>
           </clientIncludes>
         </configuration>
       </plugins>
     <pluginManagement>
   </build>
..
</project>
```

Based on the [default life cycle binding](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_ejb_packaging) there is no need to make an execution block cause [maven-ejb-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/) is already part of the life cycle. So only need to align the configuration to your needs.

Furthermore you should think about making a separate module which contains the ejb part and you shouldn't combine war and ejb part together in a single module.

Comment: It is already a separate module, there is no web component/code in it.  I created it as web module because Tomee server seems to like that better.  I've tried create it as ejb and packaged it in a ear and deployed the ear to Tomee.  It deployed successfully.  But I was not able to get a remote client to connect to it.  The one way I can get remote client to talk to the ejb server is package and deploy it as webapp.

Comment: Yes, I seem that doc.  As mentioned, I'm able to deploy to Tomee as webapp and as ejb in ear.  But when I do remote client ejb call, only webapp layout work.  This is from the link ==> Read on to learn more about packaging EJBs in a WAR file... The rest of the article kind of tell me how to deploy ejb as webapp.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work after removing the phase and adding the goal of ejb to the maven-ejb-plugin.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>BossClient</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                        <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                        <clientIncludes>
                            <clientInclude>/com/**</clientInclude>
                        </clientIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ejb</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```